# How can I describe type indexing using it's own keys in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript, sorry if my question is dumb.
Is there a way to point out the indexing for this type so that it use it's own keys instead of just an **object**?

```
 export type TypeAbCreationModal = {
  [index: string]: object | TypeExperience;
  name: {
    title: string;
    placeholder: string;
  };
  server: {
    title: string;
    tooltip: string;
  };
  site: {
    title: string;
    placeholder: string;
    placeholderSearch: string;
  };
};
```

**Edit:**
Object typed with `TypeAbCreationModal` looks like this :

```
const myObj = {
  name: {
      title: 'Some Title',
      placeholder: 'Some Placeholder',
    },
  server: {
      title: 'Some Title',
      tooltip: 'Some Tooltip',
    },
  site: {
      title: 'Some Title',
      placeholder: 'Some Placeholder',
      placeholderSearch: 'Some Placeholder',
    },
}
```

At some point I'll have to access it like this

```
myObj[someIndex].title
```

(`someIndex` is of the `TypeExperience` type)
If I use an object as an index TS throws an error "title can not assign to object"

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? Are you trying to avoid the properties of a standard javascript object and only the ones you added?

Comment: Added more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[index: string]: object | TypeExperience;` means `TypeAbCreationModal` can have any string key whose potential values are either `TypeExperience` or a primitive js `object` type, which don't have the properties you're trying to access. You probably want something like this instead of a primitive js object type:

```
interface MyObject {
      title: string,
      placeholder?: string,
      placeholderSearch?: string,
      tooltip?: string
}
```

Then update `TypeAbCreationModal` to use your new type, you don't need `TypeExperience` here:

```
[index: string]: MyObject;
```

BTW: I would change `TypeAbCreationModal` to not use `type` but rather `interface` (the `type` construct is usually used for creating union types or type aliases):

```
export interface TypeAbCreationModal {
 [index: string]: MyObject;
}
```

**Note:** The above setup will allow `TypeAbCreationModal` objects to have **any** string key so long as the value is of type `MyObject`, of which has optional properties. It's possible you don't want this but rather very specifically for it to only have a `name`, `server`, and `site` properties which can all have strict
types of their own. This gives you more type safety (although much more verbose):

```
interface MyBaseObj { 
  title: string 
}

interface MyNameObj extends MyBaseObj {
  placeholder: string;
}

interface MyServerObj extends MyBaseObj {
  tooltip: string;
}

interface MySiteObj extends MyNameObj {
  placeholderSearch: string;
}

interface TypeAbCreationModal {
 name: MyNameObj,
 server: MyServerObj,
 site: MySiteObj
}

const myObj: TypeAbCreationModal = {
  name: {
      title: 'Some Title',
      placeholder: 'Some Placeholder',
    },
  server: {
      title: 'Some Title',
      tooltip: 'Some Tooltip',
    },
  site: {
      title: 'Some Title',
      placeholder: 'Some Placeholder',
      placeholderSearch: 'Some Placeholder',
    },
}

console.log(myObj["name"].title);
console.log(myObj["server"].tooltip);
console.log(myObj["site"].placeholder);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I was looking for.